# LINQ ToDictionary From Enumerable of Anonymous Object

Tags: c#, linq

The ToDictionary() method call in this LINQ statement needs arguments. As it currently stands, the ToDictionary portion is a red squiggly, for lack of a better technical term. Error: No overload takes 0 arguments. Yeah, I know that.

I cannot add lambdas to the ToDictionary method call because Intellisense is overriding my lambda with its suggestion. In other words, if I type in "x ", it replaces it with XmlReader. Argh.

I've tried it with and without AsEnumerable. I borrowed most of this code from a StackOverflow post, but I added the dictionary portion.

Am I missing parentheses somewhere or something? Halllllp!

```
var props = (from p in _type.GetProperties()
             let attr = p.GetCustomAttribute<ExcelExportAttribute>()
             where attr != null && attr.ReportId.ToString() == reportID
             select new {Prop = p, Att = attr })
             .AsEnumerable()
             .ToDictionary<PropertyInfo, ExcelExportAttribute>();
```

#### Error in VS

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error CS1929  'IEnumerable<>' does not contain a definition for 'ToDictionary' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable, Func, IEqualityComparer)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable' WFG.UtilityLib.Excel C:\Users\kbessel\source\repos\WFG.UtilityLib.Excel\WFG.UtilityLib.Excel\ExcelExport.cs    142 Active

Comment: `.ToDictionary(item => item.Prop, item => item.Att);`: you should provide *key* and *value*

Comment: Also you don't need the `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: again, i can't add a lambda to the ToDictionary call.

Comment: Please check if you have  `using System.Linq;` since `ToDictionary()` is an *extension method*.

Comment: @KayBee718 Just press ESC when itellisense starts suggesting stuff for your lambda.  I find it annoying as well.

Comment: FYI, you can always ESC or Backspace your way out of Intellisense suggestions. And as said already, make sure that you have `using System.Linq;` on top.

Comment: After adding a lambda, the rest of the linq query is red squiggly.

Comment: Yes, I have System.Linq.

Comment: Everything before ToDictionary is now in error mode.

Comment: `Everything before ToDictionary is now in error mode` <= Compile your code and paste the compile time error in the question.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1929 'IEnumerable<<anonymous type: PropertyInfo Prop, ExcelExportAttribute Att>>' does not contain a definition for 'ToDictionary' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.ToDictionary<PropertyInfo, ExcelExportAttribute>(IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>, Func<PropertyInfo, ExcelExportAttribute>, IEqualityComparer<ExcelExportAttribute>)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>' WFG.UtilityLib.Excel C:\Users\kbessel\source\repos\WFG.UtilityLib.Excel\WFG.UtilityLib.Excel\ExcelExport.cs 142 Active

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to completely leave out the generic types, like this:

```
.ToDictionary(x => x.Prop, x => x.Att);
```

The reason is that the extension method would need not two but THREE generic types: one for the "this" parameter, and two more for the "regular" parameters - or none, because the compiler can derive the types from the parameters.

You can specify all 3 types explicitly, but that would hardly serve any purpose because they can be derived automatically.

Comment: You can keep the `.Select`. This line replaces just the original `.ToDictionary<PropertyInfo, ExcelExportAttribute>()` part + explains why it needs to be different. If you do "Go to Definition" on the .ToDict call, you'll see it is defined with 3 generic types, not 2 as you attempted to do.

Comment: Should you not be familiar with how **extension methods** work, then it is definitely worth reading up on that (it's a highly used feature these days, and Linq would not be the same without it).

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot add lambdas to the `ToDictionary` method call because Intellisense is overriding my lambda with its suggestion. In other words, if I type in "x ", it replaces it with `XmlReader`.

This is a straightforward problem to overcome: type `x`, then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close down Intellisense drop-down. Continue typing the expression as needed:

```
var props = _type.GetProperties()
    .SelectMany(p => new {Prop = p, Attr = p.GetCustomAttribute<ExcelExportAttribute>()})
    .Where(p => p?.ReportId?.ToString() == reportId)
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Prop, p => p.Attr);
```

Comment: Thank you. Now that I've added a lambda and removed AsEnumerable(), everything prior to ToDictionary() is in error mode (red squiggly).

Comment: Thanks, but there are errors in the simplified code that I can't figure out with my limited understanding of Linq. It doesn't like the Select or the reportId.

Comment: Actually, it's just the Select.    Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'ExcelExportAttribute' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'ExcelExportAttribute' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WFG.UtilityLib.Excel C:\Users\kbessel\source\repos\WFG.UtilityLib.Excel\WFG.UtilityLib.Excel\ExcelExport.cs 149 Active